# 5.5cm x 10.5 cm user manual text size

Tags: text

I am having a little problem with the readability of the text on this doc The document it self is small there fore the text size is like 2.5 pt I can not do more cuse there is no space on the paper. Any ideas of what can it be a possible solution.

Thnaks

Comment: A bit more context - including a sample of what you got, and what the whole thung is meant for - would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the format or the content are your only options. Even the best font wouldn't make much difference if no one can read the text to begin with - the manual would just be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to something which is to be printed..

2.5pt text, in *any* typeface, is entirely unreadable. In addition, it is most likely *unprintable*. At that size glyphs will plug up and become more dots than characters.

The *only* options you have are:

1. Reduce the amount of content in order to increase the font size. I'd
   suggest a minimum of 6pt type. You maybe able to get away with 5pt
   type though. I'd suggest sans serif typeface with even width strokes
   so that each glyph carries the relative same contrast.
2. Increase the size of the document in order to retain content but
   increase the type size.

Form vs. Function.

If the function of the piece is to be readable, you *must* change the form, be that content or document size.

Answer (score 0):

At 2.5, your options are limited, but there are a few things you can do that will significantly improve legibility. First, make sure you're using a sans serif font. Next, reduce the width of the characters from 100% to 97%. This doesn't make a visible impact per character, but it has a cumulative effect of significantly reducing the footprint of a page of text. Next, expand the tracking to take up the space made available by reducing the character width. These two steps will result in the same overall footprint of the "vanilla" text, but with opened opened spacing to make distinguishing the characters easier at that size.
The result will be subtle, but should improve readability.
[image]